# Bootstrap dateimepicker enable specific times

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, datetimepicker

How can i enable specific times using the bootstrap datetimepicker inside MVC project? with whatever date i want user to only pick 09:00, 11:00 and 14:30 all the other times should be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using enabledHours and disabledHours. 
Please read this [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/)

Comment: Hi thanks the documantion is a bit brief however i have managed to pick up a few features that are not exactly the solution i had in mind but they are close, this is my javascript:
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm',
                enabledHours: [09, 11, 14],
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                stepping: 30 i was hoping to have the time picker to cycle only through three specific time 09:00, 11:00 and 14:30